# Why is class related onclick event only triggered once?

Tags: jquery

I have bound this method to all elements of class `.delete_filter`. 
First I get the 'data' attribute which contains the url which should be called by the method. Then I call a script which isn't doing anything else then replacing all divs that are being reloaded with a typical "wait... loading data" div. It works fine but only once after its called one I can click on the other links as often as I want and nothing happens and this is driving me crazy and I've already gotten really angry!

```
$(".delete_filter").click(function() {
     url=$(this).attr('data');
     $.getScript("http://blabla.com/ajax/wait/filters:info", function() {
          $.getScript(url);
     });
});
```

Where is the fail?

Comment: Are the `$('.delete_filter')` elements being removed or added to the page after load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the DOM, The Div you are changing might contain the elements that you attached them the click event.

If that is the case you should use `on`\ `live`\ `delegate` functions.
Those functions will "work" the same for elements that currently rendered and elements that will be added dynamic later on.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version:

```
$("body").on("click", ".delete_filter", function(){
         url=$(this).attr('data');
         $.getScript("http://blabla.com/ajax/wait/filters:info", function() {
              $.getScript(url);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do not advice usage of `live` it is depricated from jQuery 1.7+ instead use `on`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. I wrote a table what to use in each version. why are you complaining? =)

Comment: It was not a complaint your answer is right but is is always better to use the latest since it has most of the bug fixes and optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a click bind to class elements, you are only applying it to elements that have that class at the time you ran the code. That means that if you are dynamically adding your `.delete-filter` class, then you will have to run your code again.

Comment: Yes the elements are reloaded when the click element is called. Should I solve this another way or is there a way to reload the javascript without reloading the whole page?

Comment: @davidb, I'm not sure how you have your script set up, but if you are loading new elements, then you will need to execute the code again to bind their click.

Comment: @davidb, CAbbott is right, I didn't know about jQuery's .on. Go with gdoron's answer

Answer (score 0):

May be due to jQuery caching the request/response. Try to change the url everytime you click. Try this.

```
$(".delete_filter").click(function() {
     var url=$(this).attr('data');
     $.getScript("http://blabla.com/ajax/wait/filters:info?r=" + Math.random(), function() {
          $.getScript(url);
     });
});
```